# Uso de la palabra "empañada", pero no la comida? Use of the word "empañada" outside of food contexts?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

Leí esta frase en mi clase de español:

> Mi opinión de los piratas ha quedado un poco **empañada** después de ver
> ese documental sobre las barbaridades que cometieron contra personas
> inocentes.

No entiendo el uso de la palabra empañada aquí. Lo busqué en el internet, específicamente en SpanishDict, y la única cosa que encontré fue esta:
[image]

Sé que la definición es para la palabra empanada y no empañada, pero no puedo encontrar ninguna definición excepto para la comida, la empanada.

Así, que significa la palabra empañada?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Empañada" es el participio del verbo [**empañar**](https://dle.rae.es/empa%C3%B1ar); en este caso corresponde a la acepción

> 5. Oscurecer o manchar el honor o la fama, amenguar el mérito o gloria de una persona o de una acción.

El texto indica que la opinión que tenía el autor del texto sobre los piratas (su honor, fama, mérito, gloria, etc.) ha empeorado tras ver el documental.

Answer (score 0):

n y ñ son dos letras completamente distintas. Cuando busques el significado de una palabra asegúrate de usar la letra correcta.
También te recomiendo que busques las palabras aquí:
https://www.rae.es/
es el diccionario de la real academia española

Answer (score -1):

**Empañada**, coloquialmente, quiere decir que no es transparente, o no es brillante.
Las gafas se empañan con el vaho (vapor de agua de la respiración).

**Empañada** no tiene nada que ver con **empanada**.
La una, intuyo, deriva de "pasada con un paño", la otra deriva de "envuelta en pan".

Comment: Buenas, Guillermo, bienvenido al sitio. El problema original se debía a un fallo en la aplicación del OP, que no muestra la ñ y no le reconoce la palabra "empañada". Sería interesante que citaras algunas fuentes, como diccionarios, para respaldar las afirmaciones que haces.